# How to filter from two JSON fields at the same time (SwiftUI)

Tags: json, filter, swiftui, field

I'm trying to filter data from two JSON fields at the same time depending on the system language: at this point, system language recognition seems to work (because different elements appears according to the system language), but for some reasons I can't find the exact code to do what I want to do...

As you can see from the code, I first tried to filter the field "data" for a specific word ("italiano" or "english"), then the field "autore" to categorize the various informations...but the results are not good: sometimes I see the same information repeated in the list, other times I only see the informations filtered from the "data" field but not from the "autore" field...

So, in conclusion, the result I would like to obtain is the following: if the system language is Italian, all the JSON data containing the keyword "italian" in the "data" field must be filtered first, and then filtered further based on the specific keyword contained in the "autore" field; if, on the other hand, the system language is not Italian (but any other language), all the JSON data containing the keyword "english" in the "data" field must be filtered first, and then - as in the previous case - filtered further based on the specific keyword contained in the "autore" field.

Do you have any advice? Because I think I'm not very far from the exact code...or maybe not :)
Thank you!

Here's the SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct HistoryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dm: DownloadManager
    let sysLanguage = NSLocale.current.languageCode
    
    var body: some View {
        if sysLanguage == "it" {
            List {
                ForEach(dm.JSON.filter {
                    $0.data == "italiano"
                }) { busso in
                    ForEach(dm.JSON.filter {
                        $0.autore == "storia"
                    }) { busso in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(busso: busso)) {
                            HStack {
                                URLImage(URL(string: busso.fotoUrl) ?? furl)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                Text(busso.titolo)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Spacer().layoutPriority(-0.1)
                            }
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Storia di Busso"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(dm.JSON.filter {
                    $0.autore == "storia"
                }) { busso in
                    ForEach(dm.JSON.filter {
                        $0.data == "english"
                    }) { busso in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(busso: busso)) {
                            HStack {
                                URLImage(URL(string: busso.fotoUrl) ?? furl)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                Text(busso.titolo)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Spacer().layoutPriority(-0.1)
                            }
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Storia di Busso"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}

struct HistoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HistoryView(dm: DownloadManager())
    }
}
```

Here's the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "8",
        "titolo": "View",
        "autore": "galleria",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "english",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-13 22:55:57",
        "foto": "foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "titolo": "Storia di Busso",
        "autore": "storia",
        "testo": "Testo di prova",
        "data": "italiano",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-10 21:11:03",
        "foto": "foto\/1a3e733334ec8948b0328af4e5b7288a.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/1a3e733334ec8948b0328af4e5b7288a.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "titolo": "Test 2",
        "autore": "ricette",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "english",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-08 10:49:56",
        "foto": "foto\/test_2.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/test_2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "titolo": "Test",
        "autore": "eventi",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "english",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-08 10:47:53",
        "foto": "foto\/coastal-wash-web.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/coastal-wash-web.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "titolo": "Immagine di prova",
        "autore": "luoghi",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "italiano",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-08 10:24:46",
        "foto": "foto\/unnamed.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/unnamed.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "titolo": "Panorama",
        "autore": "galleria",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "italiano",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-07 11:21:53",
        "foto": "foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "titolo": "Comune di Busso",
        "autore": "contatti",
        "testo": "Indirizzo, telefono, mail, altri dati da inserire",
        "data": "italiano",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-01 19:33:56",
        "foto": "foto\/DSCN0914.JPG",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/DSCN0914.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "titolo": "Chiesa",
        "autore": "commercio",
        "testo": "Testo di prova, abbastanza lungo per verificare l'impaginazione e correggere eventuali errori.",
        "data": "english",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-01 19:32:02",
        "foto": "foto\/CAM_0044.JPG",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/CAM_0044.JPG"
    }
]
```

Here's the DownloadManager code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DownloadManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var JSON: [BussoModel] = []
    @Published var searchText: String = "" {
             didSet {
                self.searchResults = self.JSON.filter { $0.titolo.contains(self.searchText) }
             }
        }
        @Published var searchResults: [BussoModel] = []

    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let bussoData = data {

                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([BussoModel].self, from: bussoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.JSON = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: In your DownloadManager, you should convert the JSON data to a local data type and then filter on the data type in your View. It will make it much easier to filter and to avoid using "english" in your views. Can you provide a link to the JSON data?

Comment: Filter in model, by whichever logic needed, and store results in published property which is used in UI.

Comment: @nicksarno Yeah, here's the [link](https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1)...and, if it helps, I added the code of the DownloadManager in the question...

Comment: You should update your question so that it is clear what the expected result should be. Are you intending that if it the language is not Italian then you should filter on `autore` first then `data`? Or should you be filtering on `data` first then `autore` for both languages?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, thanks for the suggestion, I'll update the question immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I believe this is what you're trying to do (unless I misunderstood something). I removed the URL image from the code, so you'll have to add it back.

A couple notes:

- Try to do all filtering and data management within the DownloadManager. I added a filter function, which is called when the data gets downloaded and also when the view gets initialized.
- Try to avoid hard coding strings into your code. I created a Language enum that will handle the "english" and "italian" filter.
- If you ever run into a situation in your code where you're duplicating a whole section (like in your post you rewrote the view for "it" and "else"), then there's definitely a better way to do it.

.

```
import SwiftUI
//import URLImage

struct HistoryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dm: DownloadManager
    let title: String
    
    init(dm: DownloadManager, autore: String) {
        self.dm = dm
        dm.filter(autore: autore)
        self.title = "\(autore)".capitalized + " di Busso"
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        List {
            if !dm.searchResults.isEmpty && !dm.isLoading {
                ForEach(dm.searchResults) { busso in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text(busso.titolo)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(busso.fotoUrl)
                            Text(busso.titolo)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 50)
                    }
                }
            } else if dm.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Text("No results.")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
    }
}

struct HistoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HistoryView(dm: DownloadManager(), autore: "galleria")
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DownloadManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var JSON: [BussoModel] = []
    @Published private(set) var isLoading: Bool = true

    @Published private(set) var searchAutore: String?
    @Published private(set) var searchResults: [BussoModel] = []
    
    let language: Language
    
    enum Language: String {
        case italian
        case english
    }

    init() {
        language = NSLocale.current.languageCode == "it" ? .italian : .english
        getData()
    }
    
    private func getData() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let bussoData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([BussoModel].self, from: bussoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.JSON = decodedData
                        self.isLoading = false
                        self.filter(autore: self.searchAutore)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func filter(autore: String?) {
        searchAutore = autore
        searchResults = JSON.filter({ (bussoModel) -> Bool in
            return bussoModel.data == language.rawValue && (bussoModel.autore == searchAutore)
        })
    }
}

struct BussoModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let titolo: String
    let autore: String
    let testo: String
    let data: String
    let extra1: String
    let extra2: String
    let creazione: String
    let foto: String
    let fotoUrl: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, that is the result I wanted...
Unfortunately, having tight deadlines for the app release, I cannot try further what you suggested, but I will surely do in the future...
In the meantime, I found a way maybe not so elegant, but that works:

`ForEach(dm.JSON.filter {
$0.data == "italiano" && $0.autore == "storia"
}) { busso in`

In this way I filter the JSON by the "data" field (language) and then by the "autore" field (category) at the same time, without writing two nested ForEach...so for the moment that's OK! Thank you again!